# How to Validation in struts 2 by Annotation for Unique field

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, annotations

I am try to make Validation in Struts 2 by Annotation and i make for all field Validation. but when am try Validation for that email is already exists. How can do that this validation
[Click Here to see Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/886mj.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. There's no built-in validation for doing a DB check, you need to create your own validation method, which you could wrap in an annotation if you really think it's worth it.

Comment: thanks you very much